# Laravel 5.7 - Login doesn't log the user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I started learning about Laravel 3 days ago and I reached a problem which I cannot fix.

When I register a user, the form works and the user is logged in.

The logout also works, but when I log in the user which has already registered, Laravel doesn't log him in. Instead, it directs the user back to the home page (or whichever route I set up the Authenticate.php file under the Authenticate.php directory).

Below, I am showing my code on the necessary files:

login view file

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
@csrf
    <input type="email" placeholder="example@me.com" class="email form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="" required autofocus>
    @if ($errors->has('email'))
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="pwd form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" value="" required>
    @if ($errors->has('password'))
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
    @if (Route::has('password.request'))
        <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}</a>
    @endif
    <div class="remember_me_wrapper input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" class="checkbox" name="remember_me" value="scales" />
        <label class="remember_me_label" for="remember_me" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
            <span></span>Remember Me
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

Login Controller file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Valiator;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logouts');
    }

    public function logout(Request $request) {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function checkLogin(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'         => 'required|email',
            'password'      => 'required|min:8',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Routes (web.php)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function (){

    Route::resource('/', "BlogController");
    Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\LoginController@getLogin');
    Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    Route::get('/logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout' );

    //register
    Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@getRegister');
    Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@postRegister');

    Auth::routes();

    Route::any('{catchall}', function($page) {
        abort(404);
    } )->where('catchall', '(.*)');

});
```

Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: You can copy login() function from AuthenticatesUsers.php (/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php) to your LoginController and then add debugging code to that function to see where it fails

Comment: @MichailStrokin I just did that. I think the only relevant piece of code in this function you referred to me, is the ```$this->validateLogin($request);``` . I checked with the rest but I didn't see any failure happening from them.

Comment: plz upload your registration code too.

Answer (score 0):

In `__construct()` method it should be `logout` not `logouts` or Do you hashed your password when you check for user's credentials. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Welcome! I use Laravel's default way of login. I am not sure where to look up for that. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: If you are using default way of login then you don't have to change in any of the file of controller or view. You just have to change .env file configuration.

Comment: Here you done changes in LoginController and as well as in web.php also.